# Commit early, commit often - does it mean "push" early, often in GIT?

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit

Having worked always in SVN, we followed the "commit early, commit often" principle with at least daily commits.
With GIT, I am unsure as to whether the same requirement make sense as the commits are not visible in the central repo until they are pushed.
Even in the git practices I can see a similar approach but it is not clear whether they talk about pushes or commits.

Comment: In Git it's a good practice to commit every change in the local repo. It's always safer to keep it for a while. If one commit might be unwanted in the future, we could just remove it from the branch history and just leave it alone. As to the `push` part, do it to upload the wanted commits when it's necessary. We can push commits that are needed to fix bugs or to implement features to the central repo in a physically remote server. Of course we can also push commits to another local repo just for backup.

Comment: Yes, sure, but that way you are not really continuously integrating, are you? Unless you update your local repo every time to check for conflicts.